# When creating a stored procedure that includes a dynamic pivot table, how do I get my parameters to work within the dynamic pivot table?

Tags: mysql

I've created a prepared statement that uses a dynamic pivot table to create a column for each Username. Everything works perfectly as is, but I am now trying to convert it to a stored procedure. My issue is that within the ' ' of the dynamic table I have several parameters that are giving me fits.

My current table and query.

```
CREATE TABLE Meeting
(
    ID INT,
    Letter VARCHAR(100),
    Username VARCHAR(100),
    Cost INT,
    billDate VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (1, 'A', 'John' , 10, '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (2, 'B','Jill' , 12, '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (3, 'A','Bob' , 15, '2020-11-21');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (4, 'T','John' , 20, '2020-11-11');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (5, 'A','John' , 8, '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO Meeting(ID,Letter,Username,Cost,billDate)
VALUES (6, 'R','Jill' , 11, '2020-11-01');
```

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @startdate = '2020-11-05';

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when Username = ''',
      Username,
      ''' then Cost end) ',
      Username
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Letter, sum(Cost), ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Meeting 
                  where billDate >= @startdate
                  GROUP BY Letter');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

If I convert it to a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `QueryReport` (startDate VARCHAR(255))
DETERMINISTIC
begin
                                           
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when Username = ''',
      Username,
      ''' then Cost end) ',
      Username
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Letter, sum(Cost), ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Meeting 
                  where billDate >= startdate
                  GROUP BY Letter');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                                           
end //
DELIMITER ;
```

and I try to call the procedure

```
CALL QueryReport ('2020-11-02');
```

I get an Error: Unknown column 'startDate' in 'where clause'.
I think it could be an issue with the ' ' from the startDate messing up the dynamic pivot table. But I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first lump of code works because user defined variable is globally available. Variables defined as parameters are not so your concat has to change

```
where billDate >= ' , char(39), startdate , char(39) , ' group by ..etc
```

Char(39) being ascii for ' (single quote)

Comment: THANK YOU!! That was exactly it. Its working perfectly!!!